# Example on how to swap solana for a token on-chain?

Tags: dapp, shadow-drive

I have a Dapp that need to use the genesysGo shadow token. I would like to ask the user to validate a transaction and pay in Solana. The on-chain program would buy the token then the front-end would be able to use the token.

Does this exist ? I don't really want to ask the user to swap some Solana for a token, it add some friction for the user.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean: User sends SOL to Program (PDA), The program converts SOL to SHDW on-chain through an AMM and using CPI (Cross program invocation).

Explain what do you mean by "the front end would be able to use the token".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The token is used to buy decentralised storage so once I have it I can use it. Do you have an example of a program/function that converts SOL to a token on-chain then AMM/CPI ? I am a bit confused about it.

Comment: Edited : In order to convert SOL to SHDW you need interact with an onchain AMM using CPI.

Comment: Not sure if there is an example but here you can find raydium instructions: https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-contract-instructions, and here how to use CPI https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/calling-between-programs